# Возвращается null в качестве результата Data.QuerysScale()

Tags: c#

Я хочу получить из таблицы номер поступления по имени товара и дате, введенной в `datetimepicker`:

```
string data = Data.Data_ret(ref dateTimePicker1); // получаю дату из datetimepicker
string tovarid = Data.QuerysScale("Select NumberOfTovar From Tovar where Name = '" + comboTovarName.Text + "'");// нахожу номер товара по имени из combobox.
string check_1 = Data.QuerysScale("Select NumberOfEntrance from Entrance where NumberOfTovar = " + tovarid + " AND Data = " + data + ""); // здесь хочу получить номер поступления по номеру товара и дате.
```

Код отрабатывает, но проблема в том, что `check_1` всегда равен `null`, хотя в таблице есть поступления товаров с датой, которую я выбрал. Кстати, этот запрос я применял к своей базе в Access, и он нормально работал. В чём может быть проблема?

Метод, которым я пользовался для получения даты:

```
static public string Data_ret(ref DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1)
{
    string[] mounth = { "января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня",
                                          "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября","декабря"};
    string Data = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    Data = Data.Remove(Data.Length - 3);
    int tmp;
    string day, preMonth;
    if (int.TryParse(Data.ElementAt(1).ToString(), out tmp))
    {
        day = Data.Substring(0, 2);
        preMonth = Data.Substring(2, Data.Length - 6).Trim();
    }
    else
    {
        day = "0" + Data.ElementAt(0).ToString();
        preMonth = Data.Substring(1, Data.Length - 5).Trim();
    }
    string year = Data.Substring(Data.Length - 4);
    var month = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < mounth.Length; i++)
    {
        if (preMonth == mounth[i].Trim())
        {
            month = "0" + (i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    var result = string.Concat(day, "/", month, "/", year);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понятно для чего нужен метод "Date_ret" если для получения даты то чем не устроило стандартное свойство

[DateTimePicker.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
//myDate будет содержать введенное поле,
//и его можно будет привести к любому необходимому формату
DateTime myDate = DateTimePicker1.Value;
```

для получения более конкретного ответа уточните структуру необходимых таблиц, какая БД. ну и пример данных для обработки

UPD

а если попробовать как то так:

```
var query = 
String.Format("Select NumberOfEntrance from Entrance where NumberOfTovar = {0} and Data='{1}'", tovarId, dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
```

а вообще формирование запросом таким образом не есть хорошо,
я бы наверно сделал например так:

```
//создаем SqlConnection
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "строка подключения"
SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;   
var query =
    "Select NumberOfEntrance from Entrance where NumberOfTovar = @tovarId and Data=@data";
var sqlParTovarId =
    new SqlParameter("@tovarId", SqlDbType.Int);
var sqlParData =
            new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlParTovarId = tovarId;
sqlParData = DateTimePicker1.Value;
var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParTovarId);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParData);
//так если возвращается несколько значений
sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while(sqlReader.Read())
{
     //делаем то что необходимо
}
//так если одно
var NumberOfEntrace = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

а вообще расмотрите возможность использования ORM(я счас использую Entity Framework) и linq. в небольших проектах думаю его использование более оправдано чем писать запросы вручную. для ознакомления посмотрите здесь [Руководство по Entity Framework](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/index.php)

Comment: попробовал через datetimepicker.value теперь в строке   string check_1 = Data.QuerysScale("Select NumberOfEntrance from Entrance where NumberOfTovar = " + tovarid + " AND Data = " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + ""); ошибка синтаксиса, пропущен оператор.

Comment: какой тип имеет поле "Date" в таблице "Entrace"?

Comment: дата/время и поле называется Data

Comment: @Роман1 обновил ответ